# Bitrix компонент в шаблоне компонента

Tags: битрикс

Как сделать более правильней и как это реализовать.

Есть карточка товара и дизайн устроен так что нужно в шаблон компонента вставить другой компонент (хлебные крошки и другое) но ведь это неправильно.

Подскажите выход из тяжелой ситуации. Мне не нужно решение, а только подсказать в какую сторону двигаться

Comment: @Санаев, почему?

Comment: @humster_spb вы еще спрашиваете почему:D Да потому что битрикс - это не самая удобная технология по моему скромному мнению

Comment: @Санаев, аргументы? не, не слышал...

Comment: @Санаев Мнений миллион. Но ситуация сложилась так что мне нужно решить проблему на этой cms

Comment: @humster_spb даже не знаю с чего и начать))) например, с гибкостью движка, галимой и глюченной структурой для масштабируемых проектов и т д )))

Comment: @humster_spb знаете как можно решить мою проблему ? ну я пробовал создать detail.php сделал обработку ссылок но тоже это не вариант ведь как вывести из компонента определенные переменные

Comment: @humster_spb вместо сms - php (для "быстрых" проектов), во всех остальных случаях java,go,python, c# и т д + front (ангуляр,реакт,вью и тд)

Comment: @Andry, я просто не очень понимаю, в чём именно у Вас проблема. Компонент в компоненте не работает? Или Вам только эстетически не нравится такое решение?

Comment: @humster_spb смотрите получается я в template.php компонента bitrix:catalog.element вставляю компонент bitrix:news.list и этот вариант неправильный из за кэширования. Плюс это не работает и правильного варианта я не нашел на просторах интернета :)

Comment: @Andry, начинаю подозревать, что задача - выводить на одной странице и детальное описание элемента, и где-то сбоку - список всех элементов, где-то сверху - хлебные крошки и т.д. Если да, то нужно просто правильно сверстать страницу detail.php: не в один компонент вставлять другой, а раскидать несколько компонентов по одной странице. Или я неправильно понял Вас? Вы бы хоть показали визуально, что требуется-то.

Comment: @humster_spb http://prntscr.com/l7ijpu Каждая страница детального элемента как landing и там получается так что много свойств у элемента несколько компонентов и устроено так что не получится сделать так что идет 1 компонент,а потом второй.

Comment: @Andry, тогда делаете несколько шаблонов одного и того же компонента с выводом разных свойств. И помещаете на странице вызовы в разных местах. А между ними уже вставляете вызовы других компонентов. Понятно объясняю? )

Comment: @humster_spb как сделать вызов ?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы было нагляднее, дам пояснение в виде ответа.

Вот, например, шаблон детальной новости:

```
    <?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
    /** @var array $arParams */
    /** @var array $arResult */
    /** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
    /** @global CUser $USER */
    /** @global CDatabase $DB */
    /** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
    /** @var string $templateName */
    /** @var string $templateFile */
    /** @var string $templateFolder */
    /** @var string $componentPath */
    /** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
    $this->setFrameMode(true);
    ?>

    <div class="news-detail">
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"])):?>

    <!-- ВЫВОД ДЕТАЛЬНОЙ КАРТИНКИ -->
            <img
                class="detail_picture"
                border="0"
                src="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                width="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
                height="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
                alt="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                title="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                />
        <?endif?>

    <!-- ВЫВОД ДАТЫ -->
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"]!="N" && $arResult["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]):?>
            <span class="news-date-time"><?=$arResult["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?></span>
        <?endif;?>

    <!-- ВЫВОД ЗАГОЛОВКА -->
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_NAME"]!="N" && $arResult["NAME"]):?>
            <h3><?=$arResult["NAME"]?></h3>
        <?endif;?>

    <!-- ВЫВОД АНОНСА -->
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"]!="N" && $arResult["FIELDS"]["PREVIEW_TEXT"]):?>
            <p><?=$arResult["FIELDS"]["PREVIEW_TEXT"];unset($arResult["FIELDS"]["PREVIEW_TEXT"]);?></p>
        <?endif;?>
        <?if($arResult["NAV_RESULT"]):?>
            <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><br /><?endif;?>
            <?echo $arResult["NAV_TEXT"];?>
            <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?><br /><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><?endif;?>

    <!-- ВЫВОД ДЕТАЛЬНОГО ТЕКСТА -->
        <?elseif(strlen($arResult["DETAIL_TEXT"])>0):?>
            <?echo $arResult["DETAIL_TEXT"];?>
        <?else:?>
            <?echo $arResult["PREVIEW_TEXT"];?>
        <?endif?>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <br />
        <?foreach($arResult["FIELDS"] as $code=>$value):
            if ('PREVIEW_PICTURE' == $code || 'DETAIL_PICTURE' == $code)
            {
                ?><?=GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_".$code)?>:&nbsp;<?
                if (!empty($value) && is_array($value))
                {
                    ?><img border="0" src="<?=$value["SRC"]?>" width="<?=$value["WIDTH"]?>" height="<?=$value["HEIGHT"]?>"><?
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ?><?=GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_".$code)?>:&nbsp;<?=$value;?><?
            }
            ?><br />
        <?endforeach;
        foreach($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>

            <?=$arProperty["NAME"]?>:&nbsp;
            <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"])):?>
                <?=implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);?>
            <?else:?>
                <?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
            <?endif?>
            <br />
        <?endforeach;
        if(array_key_exists("USE_SHARE", $arParams) && $arParams["USE_SHARE"] == "Y")
        {
            ?>
            <div class="news-detail-share">
                <noindex>
                <?
                $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.share", "", array(
                        "HANDLERS" => $arParams["SHARE_HANDLERS"],
                        "PAGE_URL" => $arResult["~DETAIL_PAGE_URL"],
                        "PAGE_TITLE" => $arResult["~NAME"],
                        "SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN" => $arParams["SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN"],
                        "SHORTEN_URL_KEY" => $arParams["SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY"],
                        "HIDE" => $arParams["SHARE_HIDE"],
                    ),
                    $component,
                    array("HIDE_ICONS" => "Y")
                );
                ?>
                </noindex>
            </div>
            <?
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Допустим, Вам надо в одном месте страницы вывести заголовок, в другом - картинку, в третьем - дату, в четвёртом - текст. Делаете 4 шаблона, в каждом из которых оставляете только нужный Вам код.

А потом в разных местах страницы размещаете вызовы компонента с подключением тех или иных Ваших шаблонов:

```
    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
        "bitrix:news.detail", 
        "имя_вашего_шаблона", // <-- здесь имя шаблона 
        array(
            "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
            "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
            "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
            "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
            "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
            "AJAX_OPTION_SHADOW" => "Y",
            "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
            "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
            "CACHE_GROUPS" => "N",
            "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
            "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
            "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
            "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
            "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
            "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
            "DISPLAY_PANEL" => "N",
            "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
            "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
            "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
            "ELEMENT_CODE" => "",
            "ELEMENT_ID" => $_REQUEST["ID"],
            "FIELD_CODE" => array(
                0 => "",
                1 => "",
            ),
            "IBLOCK_ID" => "1", // <-- здесь ID вашего инфоблока
            "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "news",
            "IBLOCK_URL" => "",
            "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
            "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
            "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
            "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
            "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
            "PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
            "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
                0 => "",
                1 => "",
            ),
            "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
            "SET_TITLE" => "N",
            "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
            "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "имя_вашего_шаблона", // <-- здесь имя шаблона
            "DETAIL_URL" => "",
            "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
            "SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
            "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "Y",
            "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
            "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
            "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
            "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "N",
            "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
            "USE_SHARE" => "N",
            "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
            "SHOW_404" => "N",
            "MESSAGE_404" => ""
        ),
        false
    );?>
```

А между ними уже можете вставлять вызовы других компонентов, любой другой код и т.д.